# Suggestions and information about SQL And Swift

Tags: ios, sql, swift, postgresql, swift3

I am working on a new app, until now i used firebase as database but this app will save much complex data and i think that firebase and noSQL at all is not the right solution in here.

I ran into this Pod: https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Swift-Kuery that helps to use `PostgreSQL` on swift.

I also ran into `ElephantSQL` that helps you to load `PostgreSQL` on an AWS server (if i got it right), but i found it pretty hard to understand everything about it and I'm not sure that this is the best solution for me.

I would love to get some help from somebody that know more on SQL and SWIFT and could help me to choose right services to use it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion to you is to avoid doing the SQL right from the mobile App unless this is extremely needed (till now I haven't found a reason to do it).

It's a better design to expose your data from your backend server (AWS, Azure, Hosted, etc) with a Webservice/API. For this you can use any backend language. Depending on your needs you could use [vapor](https://vapor.codes/) which is a web framework based on swift so that you wouldn't have to learn another language.

Comment: Thank you, can i ask why you suggest to avoid SQL?

Comment: Also i saw that vapor supports PostgreSQL, MySQL and MongoDB, so eventually i still save the data on SQL or Mongo Database, am i right about that?